# What does Deitel and Deitel mean by “expressions with side effects should not be passed to a macro”?

Tags: c++, macros

I have these questions about the red marked part of the image?
Image is snipped from Deitel & Deitel C++ Appendix E : Preprocessors

1. What does it mean when we say "Expressions with side effects"?
2. I think the purpose of author is that we should not change the value of variables existing in macro's replacement am I right?
3. I did not understand the part about common error at all. Can you explain it by code?

> [image: snipped from Deitel & Deitel C++ Appendix E : Preprocessors]

Answer (score 2):

> What does it mean when we say " Expressions with side effects" ?

Expressions like `++a`. If you have something like `#define max(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))` and if you do `max(++foo, bar)`, this macro expands to `(++foo) > (bar) ? (++foo) : (bar)`, which possibly increments `foo` twice.

> I think the purpose of author is that we should not change the value of variables existing in macro's replacement am I right?

No, I don't think this is the purpose.

> really I did not understand at all about the Common error. Can you explain it by code?

For example, let's say you did declare the aforementioned `max` macro. From that point on, so long as you do not `#undef` that macro, you're going to have problems using anything called `max`. For instance, this won't compile: `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

Answer (score 1):

Expressions with side effects are those that do something other than return a value. For example:

```
#define PRINT_TWICE(x) std::cout << (x) << "," << (x)
int i = 0;
PRINT_TWICE(i++);
```

Won't print 0 twice then set i to 1 like a function call would, it will print 0 and 1 then set i to 2.

The part about common errors mean for example if I define a macro `max` (like windows annoyingly does) then when I try to call `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` I'll get a syntax error because the last part will be replaced by the max macro. This can be avoided by conventions like making all macros uppercase but then you might still have collisions with someone else defining constants as uppercase for example.